# TeamCity Build Order

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity

I have three Build Steps at the moment, each one using a solution file (.sln). Each of these solution files have many project files in them that need to be built in a specific order. I can ensure that the build order is right in Visual Studio by messing with the Dependencies, but how do I specify that they are being built in the right order in TeamCity? Does TeamCity use the build order that is established in VS? From what I've been reading it does not, so I am not sure how to specify my own build order for the project files in each solution, or if it is even possible. Ive noticed the Dependencies option in TC, but that seems like its for one Build Step depending on another, rather than the project files depending on other project files in each solution. Is there an easy way to configure the Build Order in TeamCity?

Comment: You may need to create your own MSBuild file with the proper dependencies. We use NANT to launch the csproj builds and that respects the dependencies. It may be as simple as how you are doing the build in TC..